# DiscordJS Giphy API "Bot not Responding error" but sends gif afterwards

Tags: node.js, discord.js, giphy-api

My Discord Bot throws an error when you execute the slash command that the bot is not responding but it still sends the gif afterwards. How could i avoid that problem?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKX7q.png)

**Code:**

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('gif')
        .setDescription('sends a gif with the given argument')
        .addStringOption((option) => option.setName('argument').setDescription('the kind of gif you want').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const param = interaction.options._hoistedOptions[0].value;
        await client.search('gifs', {"q": param, "limit": 100})
            .then((response) => {
                let totalResponses = response.data.length;
                let responseIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalResponses);
                let gif = response.data[responseIndex];

                interaction.channel.send({
                    files: [gif.images.fixed_height.url]
                });
            });
    }
}
```

I have literally no idea how to fix this. Maybe the Api Responds too slow and discord thinks its not responding?

Comment: Every interaction must be replied to directly within 3 seconds, or it will be considered as failed. You're currently only sending a message to the channel; reply to the interaction with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord Interactions need to be replied to within a certain amount of time or else Discord drops them, using `interaction.channel.send` doesn't affect the interaction since you need to use `interaction.reply`, that simple switch should solve it.